# java.lang.NullPointerException in HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I am getting following exception. The exception always comes back to the line:

```
      Session session = HibernateUtil.getDefaultSession().openSession();
```

**Here is a trimmed version of the stacktrace**:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/examAdmin] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.AddCartDAO.deleteUnknownCartProduct(AddCartDAO.java:105)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

**My HibernateUtil looks like--**

```
    public class HibernateUtil {
        private static SessionFactory factory;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       private HibernateUtil() {
       try {
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
           } catch (Throwable ex) {
           System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
  }

public static SessionFactory getDefaultSession() {
       return factory;
}
```

**And my DAO looks like something**

```
 public void deleteUnknownCartProduct(String uid, String status) {
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getDefaultSession().openSession();
  Transaction tx = null;
  try {
     tx = session.beginTransaction();
     String hql = "Delete AddCart a where a.userid=:userid and a.status=:status";
     Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
     query.setParameter("userid", uid);
     query.setParameter("status", status);
     query.executeUpdate();
     tx.commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
     if (tx != null)
     tx.rollback();
     e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
     session.close();
}
}
```

I have been trying numerous different things and  Have tried as stackoverflow suggested however and still get same null-pointer at same line of code..

**My folder structure:**

[image]

Comment: pls show deleteUnknownCartProduct method , and what in line : AddCartDAO.java:105 ?

Comment: @sbjavateam question edited..

Comment: what's in line AddCartDAO.java:105 ???

Comment: @sbjavateam line-105 Session session = HibernateUtil.getDefaultSession().openSession();

Comment: @sbjavateam, actually i'm new in hibernate so i'm not able to figure it out what are you saying, so please can you explain

Comment: @sbjavateam i'm printed s.o.p as mentioned but that line is not printed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that the exception is thrown in this line:

```
   Session session = HibernateUtil.getDefaultSession().openSession();
```

Since `HibernateUtil.getDefaultSession` is a static method, this means that `getDefaultSession()` is returning `null`.

Then we look at `getDefaultSession()` and it is simply returning the the value of `factory`.  ThisgetDefaultSession implies that `factory` is `null`.  How come?  Because your code is not initializing it!!

I can see you are attempting to initialize it in a constructor.  But that can only work if you *call* the constructor.  And you don't!

A better solution is to use a static method to do the initialization; e.g.

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory factory = initFactory();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static initFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getDefaultSession() {
        return factory;
    }
}
```